# Extjs combo initial value after loadRecord before loading store

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have a problem with combobox initial value. I'm using form.loadRecord() and form.updateRecord() to load form values and insert them to grid. It works ok except for the combo values. I load store for combo on demand when it is clicked, so after the initial loadRecord() I get an int value with id. I have both smthid and smthname columns on grid.

I tried to change the value beforerender but as suspected it gets propagated to grid. I need to somehow change the initial value of the combo without writing it to the grid when the value is not int.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setValue()` or `setRawValue()` on the Combo. This should set the display, but not save the record until you `updateRecord()` manually.