# ExtJS lazy combo initial value

Tags: combobox, extjs4, initialization, lazy-loading, paging

I have lazy loaded combo in ExtJs form. Form data are loaded to form from grid store by form.loadRecord(). The lazy combo items are pairs `'value' => 'DisplayedName'` and of course each of records in grid store has already its own `'valuexyz'` to be set to combo after the record is loaded to form. **The problem is** that when the record is loaded to form, there are no items in combo yet (combo is lazy, and its items are loaded only when it is clicked) a so combo cannot to display proper `'DisplayNameXyz'` corresponding to `'valuexyz'` of loaded record. Even if combo get loaded, it is paged (by 25 items per page) and so it is quite possible that the record `'valuexyz'` for combo will not be included in the first page of loaded combo items. Combo stays empty.

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

*I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805164/extjs-combo-initial-value-after-loadrecord-before-loading-store) but it is quite brief and I'm not sure even if it is correct and how to implement it.*

Answer (score 1):

If you need data to exist in the combobox store that may not be loaded yet due to paging, then you have to get rid of the paging.

Comment: quite not possible when where are hundreds of combo items

Comment: Then you need to load the combobox store differently.  Maybe you could load the store with a targeted query that is guaranteed to return the record you need along with the rest of the 24 items in the page.